# combobox doesn't use vcl style highlight color.

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, vcl-styles

I'm using a combobox with the vcl styles enabled, but when i run the application the highlight color used by the combobox is the windows highlight color and not of the vcl styles.

How i can fix this, i mean use the vcl style highlight color in the combobox?

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As far i know, the only workaround for this issue, is ownerdraw the combobox

Try these steps

1. Set the Style property of the combobox to `csOwnerDrawFixed`
2. In the OnDrawItem event use the vcl styes methods to draw the combobox items.

Check this sample code

```
uses
 Vcl.Styles,
 Vcl.Themes,

procedure TForm115.ComboBox1DrawItem(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer;
const
  ColorStates: array[Boolean] of TStyleColor = (scComboBoxDisabled, scComboBox);
  FontColorStates: array[Boolean] of TStyleFont = (sfComboBoxItemDisabled, sfComboBoxItemNormal);
var
  LStyles  : TCustomStyleServices;
begin
  LStyles  :=StyleServices;
  with Control as TComboBox do
  begin
    Canvas.Brush.Color := LStyles.GetStyleColor(ColorStates[Control.Enabled]);
    Canvas.Font.Color  := LStyles.GetStyleFontColor(FontColorStates[Control.Enabled]);

    if odSelected in State then
     Canvas.Brush.Color := LStyles.GetSystemColor(clHighlight);

    Canvas.FillRect(Rect) ;
    Canvas.TextOut(Rect.Left+2, Rect.Top, Items[Index]);
  end;
end;
```

For more info you can check this article [`Vcl Styles and Owner Draw`](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2012/03/14/vcl-styles-and-owner-draw/). Also you can use the [Vcl.Styles.OwnerDrawFix](http://code.google.com/p/vcl-styles-utils/source/browse/trunk/Common/Vcl.Styles.OwnerDrawFix.pas) unit (part of the  [vcl-styles-utils project](http://code.google.com/p/vcl-styles-utils/)) which incudes a set of owner draws routines for components like TListBox, TComboBox and TListView.

Answer (score 4):

That should be one for RRUZ. :)
See his blog post: http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2012/03/14/vcl-styles-and-owner-draw/

(keep the rep for his soon-to-come answer, but you'll get a start ^_^)

Comment: Yeah, I'm waiting for the first question which asks how to query VCL styles with WMI.....